# Meaning of Null in Java and SQL code

Tags: java

Hi I'm a little bit confused with this code, I just want to know if why is the value of object `Connection`, `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` are `null`? Can anyone help me explain what's the function of each code below? And why are they `null`?

```
public class loginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn=null;

    ResultSet rs=null;

    PreparedStatement pst=null;

    public loginForm() {
        initComponents();
        conn = SqlConnnector.ConnectDb();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously `SqlConnector.ConnectDb()` is for getting a database connection object. None of the other fields is being set to anything other than `null`, this is why they are `null`.

Comment: Also there is no SQL code here.

Comment: Database related elements have nothing to do in a `LoginForm` by the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are being set to null to be explicit.  An alternative is to just declare them like this:

```
Connection conn;
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement pst;
```

Either way all those statements are doing is allocating a space in memory for that object.  Later they will be initialized as in the line:

```
conn = SqlConnector.ConnectDb();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have class-level variables that you want to access in various methods of the class; so by convention you set the initial value to null.  In this case, that would be the best solution as you won't be able to set them to any useful value unless you hard-code your information needed to create a connection to the database.

You would have other methods that would use the `conn` variable that contains a `Connection` object to create a `PreparedStatement` object to store in the variable `pst` and then you would use that `pst` to create a Result Set object stored in the variable `rs`.  Then you get to loop through the `rs` object to get your data.

Comment: They are actually instance variables, not class (those would be static). These variables are set to null implicitly, no need to initialise them to null. The assignments are redundant.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I forgot the correct terms.  Thanks for the correction.  The assignment to null is redundant, but I like to remind folks they are null.

Answer (score 0):

Connection, ResultSet and PreparedStatement are instance variables if you are more familiar with the term "pointer" then that what they are and assigning a null to them is like saying this pointer does not point to an object (instance) as of yet.